# How can I determine a module to which function is related with IDA Pro

Tags: ida, binary-analysis

For example I have a function sub_7FFA95D8F120. I've checked out **Views->Segments** which shows .text segment. It seems that I am missing out something important. It would be great if someone explained or gave a link to explanation.

Comment: I mean in debug process I have interaction between two libraries(Lib1 calls Lib2) and at some point I am in a function that I am interested in. And I wanted to know is my function from Lib1 or Lib2.

Comment: doesn't ida show you the module if it is externali I think ida differentiates imports with pink color  and sub is normally a prefix for a function that is  within the module being analysed  it iirc doesnt point to an external module  (and icould havewritten an answer but your questionis still  unclear evenafter your comment)

Comment: I didn't know that sub_ prefix is used for functions that belong to module that was analyzed. It makes sense now, because in most cases I generate function (with P hotkey) when I stop in the middle of unprocessed asm code(and new generated function also have sub_ prefix). Everything that wasn't processed at first doesn't belong to processed module :) Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At debug time:

- segments belonging to runtime-loaded DLLs are marked with their names (`kernel32.dll` etc.),
- non-module areas (e.g. heap) have names like `debug038`,
- segments coming from the IDB retain their original names,

so `.text` most likely belongs to the input .exe/.dll (whichever was used to create the IDB). You can also check the *Modules* view to see the start and size of each module in the process.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that Modules view have Base and Size info because usually I minimize it in order to see only module name(for search purposes). Also, remark about .text segment was useful.